# "Dammit" vs. "damnit"

Tags: orthography, offensive-language, consonants

What is the correct spelling, *dammit* or *damnit*? And what is the difference?

Just writing this question brings up a red squiggly underneath *damnit* and the suggestions include *dammit* and *damn it*.

Comment: Nobody (as far as I know) pronounces the *'n'* in *damnit*, whereas the *'n'* is pronounced in words like *damnation* and *hymnal*. So *dammit* is a more phonetic spelling.

Comment: Well, I suppose it depends on whether you mean, "build a dam across that valley" or "this sucks"  

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The usage stats from the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) look as follows:

```
            ALL SPOKEN FICTION MAGAZINE NEWSPAPER ACADEMIC NON-ACAD MISC

dammit      125    3      99       3        8        0         7      5
damnit        no results
damn it     158   12     137       1        1        0         2      5
```

And here are the stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

```
            ALL SPOKEN FICTION MAGAZINE NEWSPAPER ACADEMIC

dammit      763   20     647      60       30        6    
damnit       94    2      86       6        0        0
damn it    1307   83    1112      58       36       18
```

The [Corpus of Historical American English (COHA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) paints the following picture:

[image: Damnit vs. dammit vs. damn it vs. darn it]

<sub>(X axis: year, Y axis: incidences per million words)</sub>

Comment: Geez, what happened in 1930- ohhhhhhh...

Comment: Damnit, why are there charts

Answer (score 9):

*Damnit* could be used, though you're better off with "dammit" or "damn it". As per [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/damnit):

> **damnit**
>   Nonstandard contraction of *damn* +‎ *it* 
>   Interjection (especially southern US)
>   Common misspelling of *dammit*.

**Edit:** As my answer points out, "damnit" is considered a misspelling of the more popular "dammit", which confirms ЯegDwight♦'s data.

Comment: I really, really wonder who decides which is the correct spelling of such words and which is not.

Comment: @SF. I originally had "correct" with quotes. As you know, correct English is decided upon by its use. People use "dammit", as well, so I wouldn't call the other "wrong". It looks like a matter of preference/style.

Comment: @Zairja  Off topic- I don't understand the downvoting of valid or valiant answers either so I upvoted you.

Comment: My book editor corrected all of my `dammit` spellings to `damnit`. I corrected his correction.

Comment: @SF The same people who realized that "ain't" should be spelled as it's pronounced, even though none of the words it's a contraction of are spelled "ai".